# Get return value of threadstarter delegate in callback

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple console application, that when its executed :

1-Launch in a new thread a method, that after some time, displays in console "generate value is finished"
2-displays immediately "main thread is finished"

This is my code :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
        Console.WriteLine("main thread is finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int GenerateValue(int value)
    {
        int milliseconds = 10000;
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
        return value*2;
    }

    private static void Start()
    {
        ThreadStart starter = () => GenerateValue(5);
        starter += () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("generate value is finished");
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(starter) { IsBackground = true };
        thread.Start();
    }
```

The amelioration that I would like to bring is to display in addition of "generate value is finished", the generated value, for example here "10".

But I cannot see how to access in the delegate callback the value returned by "GenerateValue(5)" :

```
    starter += () =>
    {
       // Is it possible here to access to the value (that will be 10) 
       // returned by GenerateValue(5)
        Console.WriteLine("generate value is finished");
    };
```

Comment: Why are you combining two lambdas together instead of just doing all of that work in a single lambda?

Comment: Could you detail your answer

Comment: It's not an answer.  It's a question.  Why are you combining two separate lambdas together in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a closure:

```
private static void Start()
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    ThreadStart starter = () =>
    {
        returnValue = GenerateValue(5);
    };
    starter += () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("generate value is finished. Returned value is {0}", returnValue);
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(starter) { IsBackground = true };
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: This is a *really* bad idea.  It's highly fragile and *dramatically* more obtuse and harder to read than it needs to be.

Comment: @CodeFuller Your suggestion isn't even returning a value from a thread at all.  It's just writing a value out to the console after it's generated, which can be done by just having both lines of code in the same delegate to begin with.

Comment: Correct, but I believe user2443476 just posted Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. And his final intension is to have value returned from the thread. My answer shows how to do this with a closure.